# Как получить объект класса Application в Fragment()?

Tags: android, android-fragment, viewmodel

Мне нужно создать ViewModel для фрагмента. В случае активности способ работал и можно было прямо в конструктор передать application. В случае фрагмента это не работает. В общем-то, нужен любой способ создания VM для фрагмента, либо интересно было бы узнать, как получить Application. Код:

```
package com.example.newsapp

import android.content.Context
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider

class CrimeListFragment : Fragment() {

    private val crimeListViewModel: CrimeListViewModel by lazy {
        val crimeListViewModelFactory = ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory(//требует Application)
        ViewModelProvider(this, crimeListViewModelFactory)[CrimeListViewModel::class.java]}



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `requireActivity().application`
2. лучше подключить DI чем фабрику
3. `AndroidViewModel` - слегка дурной тон. если во ВьюМодели нужен контекст - в логике, где-то косяк.

Comment: А где можно про это подробнее почитать? Я только начинаю заниматься Андроидом и не слышала об этом.

Comment: @aRINstotle лучше использовать обычную ViewModel, но раз только начинаешь изучать - забей и использую то, что пока удобнее и проще. DI - тоже куча статей в инете, но рекомендую выбирать между Koin и Hilt (сам за Koin голосую).